# What is Confinement and Bounds in programming?

Tags: memory-management

I don't understand the difference between "confinement" and "bounds" in programming. I always understood these two to be the same thing.

Could someone explain:

- What are they?
- What is the difference between these two?

Comment: Please give some actual examples of the usage of these two terms (in the memory management context) so that we can understand what you are asking.

Comment: But from an English perspective, consider a jail cell.  The bounds are 3 meters by 3 meters.  The confinement rule is that the prisoner must stay within the cell (except for 1 hour of exercise per day ... or whatever).

Comment: @StephenC "Confinement restricts a process to reading from and writing to certain memory locations.
Bounds are the limits of memory a process cannot exceed when reading or writing." Found from internet. I also have same problem.

Comment: So ... write that as an answer.   Because that is the answer.